# Verifying/Publish Contract Source Code on BScscan not working

Tags: contract-development

Verify & Publish Contract Source Code

Contract Address: 0xbb4b79a046d34c68803a755a87c8b78bdde60aa8
Solidity (1 file)
v0.6.12
No License

I put this in.

Enter the Solidity Contract Code below *

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

import "https://github.com/safemoonprotocol/Safemoon.sol/blob/main/Safemoon.sol";

contract CANINE is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20("CANINE", "K9") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

I get an error: `Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])`

This token is already on the blockchain and the code cannot be reversed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you deployed this contract was optimisation enabled? While verifying select the same optimisation settings as were at deployment time.